# What forms the emulsion in chocolate?

Tags: food-chemistry, mixtures

Some days ago, before buying a chocolate I read the ingredients and saw that it contains a natural emulsifier. A Google search didn't reveal anything about of what the emulsion formed is, do you have any idea?

The general composition of chocolate:

> The main components in milk chocolate is cocoa butter, sugar, and milk
>   powder.

Then, a concrete example:

> Hershey’s chocolate is made of sugar, chocolate, cocoa butter, cocoa
>   processed with alkali, milk fat, lactose (milk), soy lecithin, PGPR
>   (emulsifier), vanillin, artificial flavor, and milk.

This is taken from [*The Chemistry of Chocolate* on ChemistryIsLife.com](http://www.chemistryislife.com/the-chemistry-of-choco)

I continue wondering what the emulsion is formed by.

Comment: Liquid chocolate is emulsion, afair lecithin emulsified.

Comment: @Mithoron yes, I'm asking why chocolate is an emulsion...

Comment: Only molten. And what else could be pretty homogeneous liquid containing fat and water?

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to provide a definitive answer. Do you have an ingredients list?

Answer (score 6):

Chocolate consists of tiny clumps of cocoa solids, sugar, and milk solids dispersed in cocoa butter.  Because the solids aren't soluble in the butter, they tend to clump up, which reduces the quality of the texture of the chocolate, it feels less "smooth."  When you add an emulsifier, the hydrophilic end tends to stick to the relatively more polar surface of the solids (the proteins in the cocoa solids, for example, or the carbohydrates) and then the hydrophobic end interacts favorably with the cocoa butter.  The coating of emulsifier tends to help the clumps stay small and well dispersed in the fat.  That makes it easier and faster to process the chocolate, and it also lets the chocolate last longer before the fat and chocolate solids start to phase separate on a macroscopic scale.